# $a,b,c$ are positive reals and distinct with $a^2+b^2 -ab=c^2$. Prove $(a-c)(b-c)<0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inequality, contest-math

> $a,b,c$ are positive reals and distinct with $a^2+b^2 -ab=c^2$.
>
> Show that $(a-c)(b-c)<0$.

This is a question presented in the "Olimpiadas do Ceará 1987" a math contest held in Brazil. Sorry if this a duplicate.

Given the assumptions, it is easy to show that

$$0<(a-b)^2<a^2+b^2-ab=c^2.$$ But could not find a promising route to pursue.

Any hint or answer is welcomed.

Comment: What happened to $d$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: Thanks (+1) fixed... there is no d.

Comment: The proposed duplicate does not require *distinct* integers, and the conclusion drawn there is a *weak* inequality.  However it is pretty evident that when the (positive) integers are distinct (as here), then the produce $(a-b)(b-c)$ cannot be zero.  Voting to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WLOG assume $a<b$. Then:
$$a^2+b^2-ab=c^2 \Rightarrow a(a-b)=(c-b)(c+b) \Rightarrow c<b$$
$$a^2+b^2-ab=c^2 \Rightarrow (a-c)(a+c)=b(a-b) \Rightarrow a<c.$$

Answer (score 8):

If $a<b$, then
$$
c^2 = a^2+b^2-ab = a^2+b(b-a) > a^2 \\
c^2 = a^2+b^2-ab = b^2-a(b-a) < b^2
$$
which means $a<c<b$ and $(a-c)(b-c)<0$.

If $a>b$, then
$$
c^2 = a^2+b^2-ab = a^2-b(a-b) < a^2 \\
c^2 = a^2+b^2-ab = b^2+a(a-b) > b^2
$$
which means $b<c<a$ and $(a-c)(b-c)<0$.

Comment: You could say the problem is symmetric in terms of $a,b$, so you can let WLOG (without loss of generality) $a>b$ (it's also given $a,b$ are distinct).

Answer (score 6):

Observe triangle with sides $a,b,c$ and angles $\alpha,\beta, \gamma$.

By cosine theorem angle $\gamma = 60^{\circ}$, thus $\alpha +\beta =120^{\circ}$. 
So we can assume $\alpha \leq 60^{\circ}$ and $\beta \geq 60^{\circ}$. So $b\geq c\geq a$ and thus conclusion:

$$(a-c)(b-c)\leq 0$$

with equality iff $a=b=c$.

Comment: How do you know that such a triangle exists?

Comment: Let $ABC'$ be a triangle with sides $a,b$ and angle 60. Does that one exist?

Comment: Yes, it does. Thanks.

Comment: How do you derive the strict inequalities from this triangle argument? It is possible e.g. by using the law of sines, but imho it is far from being obvious.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what are you asking me? Where is a problem? Did I miss something in my prove?

Comment: My fault, I am sorry. I thought there was something you missed, but there is not. Please ignore my comment.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a\le b$

$a,b,c$ - sides of $\triangle ABC$ with $\angle BCA= 60^o$ , $BC=a , AC=b$.

$\Rightarrow a\le c\le b \Rightarrow (a-c)(b-c)\le 0$

Comment: There's already a similar posted answer.

Answer (score 1):

we get $$c=\sqrt{a^2+b^2-ab}$$ since $c>0$ and $$a^2+b^2>ab$$ from here we get
the product
$$(a-\sqrt{a^2+b^2-ab})(b-\sqrt{a^2+b^2-ab})<0$$
we have two cases.
1) $$a>\sqrt{a^2+b^2-ab}$$ and $$b<\sqrt{a^2+b^2-ab}$$ after squaring we get $$a>b$$
2) $$a<\sqrt{a^2+b^2-ab}$$ and $$b>\sqrt{a^2+b^2-ab}$$
after squaring we get $$a<b$$ and our Statement is true.

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality you can supose $a>b$. Then there are 2 cases you got to disprove (sorry if this word does not exist, english is not my first language)

Case 1) $a>b>c$ and Case 2) $c>a>b$.

Any other case, satisfies the proppert (Since a,b, and c are dsitinct)

Case 1)

If $a>b>c$ then $b^2>c^2$ and $a^2-ab > 0 $ (since a > b).

Then $a^2 +b^2 -ab > c^2 + 0$. Then it contradicts the hypothesis.

Case 2)

If $c>a>b$ then $c^2>a^2$ and $0>b^2-ab$ then $c^2=c^2+0>a^2+b^2-ab. Contradicting the hypothesis again.

Keep in mind this can all be done only because they ae positive real numbers.